# Django profile picture does not upload

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-media

This question was asked I don't know how much but it doesn't give my answers
The app I was gonna make is a little blog webapp from a tutorial (for some training in Django, it's the first time I use it so...)
There is my code:

```py
# models
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

# Create your views here

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Well, that's not all:

```py
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(
            request.POST,
            instance=request.user
        )
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(
            request.POST,
            request.FILES,
            instance=request.user.profile
        )
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'title': 'Profile',
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

At this time, I changed all my settings and I did some html code:

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <div class="media">
            <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
                <p class="text-secondary"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- FORM HERE -->
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
                {{ u_form|crispy }}
                {{ p_form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Not any errors, the post request works very well, I don't know what to do so...

Comment: Whats wrong? your image is not saved? or is not displayed?

Comment: @Walucas Yep it's saved `u_form.save() p_form.save()`

Comment: do you see it on your directory? does your template displays the username?

Comment: add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form>` tag.